# Having the length of two inputs be defined by another input

Tags: python, variables

I'm pretty new to python and have been using a website with different problems to help me learn more about the language. The problem I'm on right now is to take integers in two separate inputs and finding the minimum between each pair
in the two inputs. I know how to do this and have already succeeded, however the problem also calls for specifying in a separate input at the beginning the number of pairs to be used.

I can't figure out how to match the number of pairs of the two other inputs to the integer entered in the first input. I've been trying to get it so the first input is the number of pairs the next two inputs will have and if they don't match it'll print an error message that I define. What way can I accomplish this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to accomplish. There is a lot wrong with this code though I'm sure.

```
def test():
    a = int(input("Enter number of pairs: "))
    b = [input("Enter first numbers: ").split()]
    c = [input("Enter second numbers: ").split()]
    for i in a:
        pairs = i
        if len(b) and len(c) != pairs:
            print("Error! Number of pairs not equal!")
        elif len(b) and len(c) == pairs:
            d = int(b)
            e = int(c)
            for g,h in zip(d, e):
                print(min(g, h))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  To help you best, please provide a complete, minimum, and verifiable example.

Comment: Please see [mcve].

Comment: Please clarify: you know how to write a program to find the minimum of two entered integers twice, and need to know how to write a program to find the minimum of two entered integers x times, where x is input by the user.

Comment: @EvanWeissburg I need to write a program where the first input is the number of pairs the next two inputs will have. So if you entered "2" into the first input the program would expect the next two inputs to have 2 numbers each. Say for example 7 and 8 and 8 and 7. If you had 7 and 8 in one input and 8, 7, and 9 in the other I'd like for it to display a error since one of the inputs has 3 instead of 2 numbers.

Comment: The problem statement is quite unclear - to increase clarity and chances of getting the most helpful answer, you might consider including the website you got the problem from and the website problem statement verbatim into your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you might want to include the number of pairs as a parameter. Or I may have not even correctly understood the question. But I can suggest a simpler solution

```
def f(num_pairs):
    if type(num_pairs) is not list or not num_pairs:
        print("No proper pair was found!")
    else:
        for pair in num_pairs:
            print(min(pair))
                                                  #Outputs:
f(5)                                              #No proper pair was found!
f([])                                             #No proper pair was found!
f([[1, 2]])                                       #1
f([[7, 2], [3, 10], [5, 2], [2, 2]])              #2
                                                  #3
                                                  #2
                                                  #2
```

I guess this is what you want:

```
def foo(num_paris, first_ones, second_ones):
    if num_paris != len(first_ones) and num_paris != len(second_ones):
        print("Wrong!")
    else:
        for first, second in zip(first_ones, second_ones):
            print(min(first, second))

                           #Outputs:    
foo(2, [], [])             #Wrong!
foo(2, [7, 8], [8])        #Wrong!
foo(2, [7, 8], [8, 7])     #7 
                           #7
foo(3, [7, 8], [8, 7])     #Wrong!
```